# schemacrawler not returning all Oracle tables - what permissions are required?

Tags: oracle, schemacrawler

Using schemacrawler and trying to connect to an Oracle database.  The resulting json file is only including about 10 tables, but we are expecting a much larger number of tables in the database.

This must be restricted by permissions of the user being used to access the Oracle database, but what permissions are required for that user for schemacrawler to be able to "see" the table/columns?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably schemacrawler uses the data dictionary. So the user will be restricted to what tables and columns are visible in ALL_TAB_COLS view i.e. what tables they have at least SELECT privilege on.

Otherwise the user needs select on DBA_TAB_COLS, which shows all tables in all schemas. That requires DBA access to grant.

Comment: Are you saying that if a user has been granted SELECT on DBA_TAB_COLS that schemacrawler would have the permissions it needs to see all the tables?